# Steps when on skava when a customer has two default payments?

Tags: payment-processing, ecom

Member number: 23935016 has two default payment method and he has an issue to process the payment, in this case I can delete the card that is not necessary? The card was deleted on BSI but isn't reflected on Skava.

Appreciate your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXgMZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

If the change was done on BSI and it didn't reflect in skava please investigate why that happened also but yes you can delete it then

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In this case, the credit card on OMS and BSI was added multiple times. What steps do I have to follow on this case?